# xcodebuild creating xcframework with embedded libraries

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcodebuild, xcframework

I have a little bit strange problem with xcodebuild xcframeworks with Xcode 12.5.

- Always when I create new framework, there is a other embedded frameworks in my new framework.
- Created xcframework is not working.

I've tried:

- Yes I did "BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION = YES"
- Yes I tried to remove folder "/Frameworks" inside created library
  ...
  Do you have any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a dynamic framework and adding other framework references to yours, be sure that under the *general* tab of your "frameworks and libraries" those are set to "do not embed" *[image: target]*

Comment: Yep I did, but still when I create "xcarchive" or at the end "xcframework" it has still some embedded libraries. But, with xcode 12.4 - libraries are not ebedded but created framework doesn't work.